# A number is added to the end of decrypted text vba access

Tags: vba, ms-access, encryption

When decrypting my code manually - in the immediate window - everything works perfectly. However, when I try to put the decrypted code in a string variable (eg. strVar = decrypt(strEcnrypedCode)), it adds a number to the end of the string variable! Any ideas?
This is the decryption code:

```
Public Function Decrypt(DataIn As String) As String
    Dim CodeKey As String
    Dim arkdata1 As Long
    Dim strDataOut As String
    Dim intXOrValue1 As Integer
    Dim intXOrValue2 As Integer
    
    CodeKey = "12345678909"
    
    For arkdata1 = 1 To (Len(DataIn) / 2)
        intXOrValue1 = Val("&H" & (Mid$(DataIn, (2 * arkdata1) - 1, 2)))
        intXOrValue2 = Asc(Mid$(CodeKey, ((arkdata1 Mod Len(CodeKey)) + 1), 1))
        strDataOut = strDataOut + Chr(intXOrValue1 Xor intXOrValue2)
    Next arkdata1
    
    Decrypt = strDataOut
End Function


Public Function Encrypt(DataIn As String) As String
    Dim CodeKey As String
    Dim arkdata1 As Long
    Dim strDataOut As String
    Dim temp As Integer
    Dim tempstring As String
    Dim intXOrValue1 As Integer
    Dim intXOrValue2 As Integer
    
    CodeKey = "12345678909"
    
    For arkdata1 = 1 To Len(DataIn)
        intXOrValue1 = Asc(Mid$(DataIn, arkdata1, 1))
        intXOrValue2 = Asc(Mid$(CodeKey, ((arkdata1 Mod Len(CodeKey)) + 1), 1))
        temp = (intXOrValue1 Xor intXOrValue2)
        tempstring = Hex(temp)
        
        If Len(tempstring) = 1 Then
            tempstring = "0" & tempstring
        End If
        
        strDataOut = strDataOut + tempstring
    Next arkdata1
    
    Encrypt = strDataOut
End Function
```

Comment: Would help to add a pice of code we can use to replicate what you’re seeing.

Comment: This line "ww-www-www-ww-325647" is encrypted to "424418544F406E4744461846526B030005720004", but when decrypted and put in a string variable it becomes "ww-www-www-ww-3256477"

Comment: I'm getting completely different results, but same in both cases. There are some flaws in your logic and you are getting ascii characters that might garble the output.

Comment: But when I put the encrypted code directly into the Decrypt("424418544F406E4744461846526B030005720004") function everything is fine. And  when I pass the code to a variable string (strVar =Decrypt(strEcnrypedCode)) things go bad., the strVar has the extra character.

Comment: I get completely different results also.

Comment: If you wish strong encryption, study my project [VBA.Cryptography](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Cryptography) based on code by @ErikA.

Comment: Without the code performing the "encryption", we can't answer this question properly. However, please use  proper encryption (link shared by Gustav, for example). This algorithm can easily be reverse-engineered and defeated only by having a couple of inputs and outputs to the encryption or decryption function. Cryptography is hard, [don't roll your own crypto](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/18198)

Comment: I included the encryption method in the main post